# Cannot read data from ELM327 device with PySerial

Tags: pyserial, obd-ii, elm327

I am trying to communicate with a ELM327 device using PySerial. However I am not able to read any data from the device. Here is the results of what I have tried in the terminal interpreter.

```
>>> import serial
>>> ELM327 = serial.Serial('/dev/serial/by-id/usb-1a86_USB2.0-Serial-if00-port0', 38400, timeout=5)
>>> ELM327.write(b'AT Z\r\n')
6
>>> ELM327.read()
b''
>>> ELM327.write(b'AT RV\r\n');
7
>>> ELM327.read()
b''
>>> ELM327.write(b'AT\r\n');
4
>>> ELM327.read()
b''
```

I have tried the same by changing the device to `/dev/ttyUSB0` but get exactly the same results. I  am running this as the *super user* as well. I also tried swapping out the `\r\n` with just `\r` and `\n` respectively. It is a ELM327 v1.5a device I'm trying to connect to. Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are not using the correct bitrate. You are sending the correct commands (although I'd skip the spaces and the \n), but the device is obviously not correctly receiving them otherwise it would have ECHOed them to you.